# Bootloader problem

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, bootloader

I don't know why or how... But my boot loader have been destroyed. In this moment I have installed on my PC Windwos 8, Ubuntu 15 and Ubuntu 14 but just Ubuntu 15 have visible on bootloader.. 
I've try more methods to resolve that but no one of them don't works:

1. First, I've install the Kali linux, I'm thinking that will be install a new bootloader and the problem can be solve, but it don't works
2. After that I've replace the Kali linux with Ubuntu 14 and Ubuntu 15, again.. I'm thinking that can solve my problem, but again, I don't have any result.
3. After that I've open Ubuntu 14.0.4 with a Live USB Stick and I've install the Boot-repair tool to repair my boot but again, it don't have any effect.
4. and the last idea what I've tried was to fallow that commands:

   Boot the machine using a Live CD.

   Open a terminal.

   Find out the name of the internal disk by using fdisk to look up the device's size.
   For example:

   `sudo fdisk -l`

   Install GRUB boot loader onto the proper disk (the example below assumes it is /dev/sda):

   `grub-install --recheck --no-floppy --root-directory=/ /dev/sda` But when I've fallow the 3rd command I've obtain that message: `WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sdb1'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.` And after I've fallow that last command I've obthan that message: `Installing for i386-pc platform.
   grub-install: error: cannot open directory /boot/grub/i386-pc: No such file or directory.`
   So that my problem, know anyone how can I solve it?

Here it's the [output](http://paste.ubuntu.com/12135052/) of boot info script.

Comment: Your install commands are to install a BIOS boot grub. But your system is UEFI, and even Ubuntu then is in UEF mode. Fdisk does not yet work on gpt partitioned drives (it will in 15.10). If you have multiple Ubuntu installs with UEFI only one is in UEFI boot menu and others should then be in grub's boot menu. There is a tiny grub.cfg in /EFI/ubuntu that has the UUID of the default install to find the main grub.cfg. Best to post link to Summary report from Boot-Repair booted in UEFI mode.

Comment: Read Rod Smith's answer; adding to that, it's very stange that you don't have a bootloader after having installed Ubuntu in any configuration possible. I'm pretty sure you're missing something (e.g. which is your frist boot device in the BIOS?)

Answer (score 1):

> my boot loader have been destroyed. In this moment I have installed on my PC Windwos 8, Ubuntu 15 and Ubuntu 14 but just Ubuntu 15 have visible on bootloader

Proper diagnosis of this type of problem *requires* more information, starting with the partition table information and GRUB configuration file. This information can all be gathered into one convenient report by the [Boot Info Script,](http://sourceforge.net/projects/bootinfoscript/) which can be installed from the `boot-info-script` package, IIRC. Run this tool and it should generate a file called `RESULTS.txt`. Post that file to [a pastebin site](http://paste.ubuntu.com/) and post a URL to your document here so that we can review it.

Absent that diagnostic information, I do have one suggestion that *might* help: Prepare a USB flash drive with my [rEFInd boot manager.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/getting.html) Unlike GRUB, which relies on a configuration file with boot options, rEFInd generates them on the fly based on its scan of available boot loaders (including Linux kernels) on your computer. Thus, rEFInd *might* enable you to boot any of your OSes. I emphasize the word *might* because there are a number of situations in which rEFInd won't help, not least of which is if you don't actually have all three OSes installed the way you think they're installed. (It's quite common for people to accidentally trash one OS or distribution when installing another one, so this is a very real possibility. The Boot Info Script output will help us figure out if that's happened to you.) Thus, the rEFInd solution is, at best, a shot in the dark; but at least trying it from a USB flash drive or CD-R is unlikely to make matters worse.

> but it don't works

In the future, always be more precise about what is and is not working. A claim that something doesn't work, with no elaboration, is unhelpful from a problem-solving perspective. Even if the symptoms are exactly what you described earlier, say so. If the symptoms differ, even slightly, describe how they're different.

> I've obtain that message: `WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sdb1'!`

Assuming this is an accurate report of the message, you've made a critical mistake: You must use partitioning tools, such as `fdisk`, `gdisk`, and `parted`, on *whole disks.* The `/dev/sdb1` device specified in this error message, though, is a *single partition.* The corresponding whole-disk device is `/dev/sdb` (with no trailing `1`). Running something like `fdisk -l /dev/sdb1` will be misleading but harmless; but if you actually created partitions inside a partition, you might have trashed whatever data existed on that partition.

As oldfred points out, `fdisk` is also useless on GPT disks, at least in Ubuntu 14.04. (15.04's `fdisk` supports GPT, though.) That said, if the output was an accurate cut-and-paste without typos, then the error of applying `fdisk` to a partition rather than a disk means that we don't really know that the disk actually is a GPT disk. This in turn means that we can't be certain that Windows is booting in EFI mode, much less that Ubuntu is (or should) be doing the same. All of this brings us back to my initial point: We need more data, in the form of Boot Info Script output, before anything conclusive can be said about what's wrong.

---

***EDIT:***

Your Boot Info Script output is helpful. Some observations:

- You have at most two Linux installations. `/dev/sda5` holds what looks like Ubuntu, and `/dev/sda6` appears to hold something else.
- Boot Info Script shows two GRUB configuration files. One identifies `/dev/sda5` as Ubuntu and does not have an entry for `/dev/sda6`. The other identifies `/dev/sda5` as OpenSUSE and `/dev/sda6` as Debian. From your description, I suspect that the first of those is active.
- Your disk is MBR and your computer is booting in BIOS/CSM/legacy mode. This is not (or should not be) a problem, but you should keep it in mind. Ignore the GPT warning you got when you tried to read `/dev/sda1` with `fdisk`. Also ignore suggestions to install an EFI version of GRUB; that will just create new problems.
- `/dev/sda5` uses ext4fs, which is the default filesystem for Ubuntu. `/dev/sda6` uses Btrfs, which is supported by Ubuntu but is not standard. Btrfs is more likely to cause problems than ext4fs, but Btrfs is more advanced. For the most part, Btrfs should be used only by experts who fully understand its features and quirks.

Your best course of action at this point is probably to run [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) on the computer. With any luck, that will fix the problem. If it doesn't, the next thought that occurs to me is to dig into manual boot loader configuration; you could install LILO or GRUB Legacy, or create a custom GRUB 2 setup that's not configured by GRUB's automatic scripts. This approach requires considerable knowledge, though. There are lots of (mostly older) Web sites that describe how to do this, but I don't have any URLs handy. Overall, though, I don't recommend that you try manual boot loader configuration; given your current level of knowledge, you'll find it frustrating.

If Boot Repair doesn't work, an easier option may be to use virtualization (VirtualBox, KVM/QEMU, etc.) rather than multi-booting. This approach bypasses the need for such a complex boot loader setup, and so is likely to be both much easier and much safer to manage. It has the drawback that you won't have direct hardware access in the guest OS(es), though, which could be an issue if you want to run games. Running OpenSUSE or Kali under Ubuntu should not be a problem, though; if you need direct hardware access, you can use Ubuntu for that. In this scenario, your OpenSUSE or Kali installation would exist so you can familiarize yourself with those distributions, not for real work. Since that's presumably the point of dual-booting two Linux distributions, this should be fine. If you go this route, you'll probably want to either erase one of your Linux partitions (probably `/dev/sda6`) and mount it within your Linux directory tree for use as data storage or delete the partition entirely and use GParted to expand the remaining Linux filesystem into that space.

Comment: I've add the output of bootinfoscript on my question. And if I've use that  grub-install --recheck --no-floppy --root-directory=/ /dev/sdb to use whole disk I've receive that error: Installing for i386-pc platform.
grub-install: error: failed to get canonical path of `/cow'.

Comment: See my edit, above.

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying Kali initiated the "catastrophe"? Or did you go to Kali expecting to go from only Ubuntu 15 to a menu with 4 systems? Or were you destroying Ubuntu 15 and Ubuntu 14 at will because you didn't have anything there, simply you wanted some multi-boot experience? Anyway, if booting into Ubuntu 15 is OK and you haven't overwritten the "correct" partitions, especially the EFI partition, then the fix should be as simple as `apt-get update; apt-get upgrade`, either from Ubuntu 15 proper or from Advanced/Recovery for Ubuntu 15, since you are certain to fetch a new `grub` version (I am guessing `grub-efi`) and reconfigure it "automatically". In the recovery session just remember to start with a disk check, and drop to a "root prompt" ideally being networked by cable.

P.S. with these Windows computers you should be installing and using `gdisk` instead of `fdisk`, and gparted if you are in the GUI. On the other hand, Boot-repair saved me more than once, of course by copying and pasting exactly what it says when it says it, you may have damaged all your important partitions already.